# Custom login page for windows authentication?

Tags: 2013, authentication, claims-based-auth, windows-authentication, custom-login-page

We are running on SharePoint 2013 On Premise, Claims Based Authentication, 
windows Authenticaton (NTLM).

Is it possible to change the normal "username/password" popup-window to a web form (of any kind). The requirements is that our code should to the authentication against the AD and if any errors occurs (for example password expired) the user should be informed on the web form.

(we are not running ADFS, but will consider it if its the only way)

I would like to keep windows authentication, since most of our users are internal and must be automatically logged in to SP. [this article (answer on one of the comments)](https://mikevallotton.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/sharepoint-2010-claims-authentication-custom-login-form-part-3-developing-a-custom-login-form/) suggests that its possible, but the article uses FBA

Answer (score 2):

Before doing the Custom login page for windows authentication, you have to configure your web application web.config file to authenticate current user credential against active directory. Here is a [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nishants/2009/05/22/how-to-configure-forms-based-authentication-active-directory-ldapmembership/) which may help you on that.

And Creating a Forms Based Authentication will be easy. You can get help from [here](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1093) on that. 
ADFS is not mandatory to these. But using ADFS will be more easier. Hope it will help.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (this goes to you too Evariste) ....  Ok, Im confused...dont you have EITHER windows based auth OR forms based auth. What is the difference between FBA with a ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider and classic windows authentication?

Comment: ok. The difference is:
Classic Windows Authentication provides Authentication system against AD. But it doesn't provide you any error message or any customized thing which you wanted. 
And a FBA with AD integration also provides  Authentication system against AD. But here you can design the from as your requirements and provides other error messages. 

in this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx#planwin) you will get some video which provides more explanation. Please Check this. If their is any confusion in further, please comment here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you need, you "simply" have to switch to Form-Based Authentication (FBA) at the Web application level, and make it point to a custom page you have to develop first. That custom page shows the form you like, and checks the credentials the way you like.

A [simple Google query](https://www.google.fr/search?q=build%20fba%20page%20sharepoint%202013) will give you all links you need to build and setup a custom FBA page.

Comment: I'd be very glad to know how to setup a custom login page without enabling FBA on the Web app. AFAIK, "custom login page" is kinda synonym of "FBA"!

Comment: The article you mention states "modify the path of the virtual folder to point to the new folder". This is something not supported and that we cannot encourage at all. It's modifying the core product, and cannot be close to any official way to achieve custom login page! As bad as modifying the built-in files.

Comment: Modify my answer in which way??